# CMake link shared library

Tags: cmake

I am trying to link shared library using cmake. The library is located at known location `/home/username/lib`. I have added `find_library` to `CMakeLists.txt` to find the library. By running ccmake I verified that the library was correctly localized. But when I generate makefile and call `make` I get error:
`/user/bin/ld: cannot find -labc`

Here is the `CMakeList.txt` file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(application)
find_package( OpenCV REQUIRED )
include_directories("include")
add_executable( application demo.cpp )
find_library(abc abc PATHS /home/username/lib)
target_link_libraries( application abc ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first parameter to `find_library` is a variable. So you should use the value of that created and filled out variable in the `target_link_libraries`:

```
target_link_libraries( application ${abc} ${OpenCV_LIBS})
```